# Single link touch/press hitting my page multiple times. (acts as if the link was clicked/pressed multiple times in a second)

Tags: php, hyperlink

I have an unusual problem.

I have a site that allows its clients to email their clients various information. Among the email's content is a link that the sender has the option to include. This link serves as an acknowledgement so that the sender knows that the receiver got and saw the email. When this link is pressed (from a via phone or computer), sometimes the system receives multiple acknowledgements and updates the sender's correspondence accordingly. Obviously this gets annoying for the sender.

The php page in question contains:

- A couple of 'includes'
- nothing that loops
- some if statements
- a php 'md5()' function
- some sql queries.

Does anyone have any idea why the page sometimes gets hit multiple times on a single click/touch?

note: This code is running on a old server

note: I haven't ruled out that this is not happening on computers, but I know for certain that it can happen when the link is pressed from a phone.

I have tried redirecting out of the page immediately after the desired code has been run.

I have tried setting session variables and timers so that the page could not get hit again from the same tab. (all session variables get dropped) This did not help, but my original thought was the receiver was just refreshing their page over and over on accident. (on a phone I thought that this made a lot of sense).

Whatever you may know could help. This is a lingering problem that always comes back.

Comment: The URL might get fetched by some sort of pre-loading mechanism, especially on mobile that might happen for performance reasons. But any other mail client might also try to fetch the URL, in an attempt to be able to render a "preview". You just discovered the main reason, why anything that does not just _request_ data, but _changes_ things on the server side, should always happen via a POST request, not a GET.

Comment: using POST instead of GET sounds promising; however, I do not know how I might go about that considering a link is all that the receiver really has to work with.

Comment: Link to a page that contains a form, and then either let the user actively submit it (if you want user participation on this) - or submit it via JavaScript on page load. (Bots that just request the URL you put into the email, don't usually interpret JavaScript.)

Comment: Having the user actively hit an 'acknowledge' button or something like that would definitely fix my problem. Thank you for the advise.